# how to read first N bytes from a file and store it in a variable - Node fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

Iam using streams but cant seem to store it in a variable

```js
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileLocation, { start: 0, end: 32 });
const data = fileStream.on("data", data => { return data });
console.log(data);
```

Also tried

```js
let fileContents = [];

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileLocation, { start: 0, end: 32 });
fileStream.on("data", data => fileContents.push(data));

console.log(fileContents);
```

Comment: This is not a synchronous operation. The callback that is passed to `fileStream.on` won't be triggered instantaneously. You might also have to wait for some sort of `complete` or `done` event before you can process the contents. Please share what NodeJS version are you using. Can you also create a reproducible example on Stackblitz and share the link here? Meanwhile, you can check out this documentation for different events of a ReadStream: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fsreadstream

Comment: @vighnesh153 iam encrypting a file and appending salt(16-bytes) and authTag(16-bytes) at the start of the file and so when decrypting i need to read the first 32 bytes and store it in a variable to use that to create the decryption key.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-grwxsz?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

`fs.createReadStream` returns a `ReadStream` instance. The `ReadStream` instance emits a bunch of events. You can tap on to those events. The events that you need are `data` and `close`. The `data` event will be triggered whenever the `ReadStream` instance reads a segment of your file. It will be triggered several times, depending on the buffer limit.

Once it is done reading, it will emit a `close` event. This is when you know that you have all chunks you needed from the file. The chunks will be in the form of buffer. You can convert it to a `utf-8` string before processing.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const fileLocation = './sample.txt';
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileLocation, { start: 0, end: 32 });

const chunks = [];
fileStream.on('data', (data) => {
  chunks.push(data);
});

fileStream.on('close', () => {
  console.log(chunks.toString('utf-8'));
});
```

Here is a promisified version of the same:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function readFileAsPromise(path, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path, options);

    const chunks = [];
    fileStream.on('data', (data) => {
      chunks.push(data);
    });

    fileStream.on('close', () => {
      resolve(chunks.toString('utf-8'));
    });

    fileStream.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}

async function main() {
  const data = await readFileAsPromise('./sample.txt', { start: 0, end: 32 });
  console.log(data);
}

main();
```

Comment: but how do i store it in a variable. If you check the Stackblitz link. I want to use it in a class and then use it.

Comment: I have stored it in a variable in the promise-based version. Check the `main` function.

Comment: i saw that but how do i use it in my class constructor and then use it.

Comment: You cannot await in a constructor. You can build a builder function which reads the data and then passes it to the constructor. This is unrelated to this question. You should post another question on how to use await in constructor.

Comment: Is there a way without using streams

Comment: You can read the entire file using "fs.readFileSync". That way, you won't need promises. But this isn't the right approach because if you are planning to scale this to multiple users, it will impact the performance. "fs.readFileSync" is a blocking operation.